# How do I fix the IDLE window colour on MacOS?

Tags: macos, python, macos-catalina

For some reason, my IDLE window is black with (presumably) black text - I can't see anything.

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Mac window titled Idle Shell 3 point 10 point 3. The main window area is black, with only a scrollbar visible on the right hand side]

Frustratingly, this problem extends to the Settings, so I can't try to sort it out there. Curiously, special elements like buttons, etc. sometimes appear properly.

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Mac window titled Settings. The main window area is black, with only a combo box and two scrollbars visible]

This is in an essentially new install of Python, on MacOS Monterey 12.1. In a bid to fix things, I installed [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and through this I'm using python 3.10.3, as far as I can tell - I'm rather new to all of this.

When I run IDLE by typing `idle` into Terminal, I get the error

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

before it starts.

How do I get IDLE displaying properly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a long shot, but does switching your system settings to dark mode (or to light mode if you were already on dark mode) make a difference? Be sure to re-launch the app after switching.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I've tried this - I was initially in dark mode - but to no avail. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue if you don't install python with tkinter support. If you have homebrew, you can run the command `brew install python-tk` (if you dont have homebrew, the long line of code that installs homebrew is copyable from [their site](https://brew.sh).